# Show div based on two select inputs

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I want to display if one of two select inputs are set to a particular option.

```
<select id="firstChoice">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="secondChoice">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div class="additional">
     ...
</div>
```

If either select is set to Option 1 then the div should show otherwise it should be hidden.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulyabsley/aKqKR/)

[edit] In an effort to be brief and with what I had tried being really bad I didn't post what I had done. Apologies for that. I've updated the above fiddle with a modified version of one of the answers below. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: We are happy to help you fix problems in your code, but this site is not a place to ask others to write your code or development plan for you. Please consider improving your question (or asking a new one) when you have a specific problem relating to your own code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var $select = $('#firstChoice,#secondChoice');
$select.on('change', function () {
    var str = "Option 1";
    if ($('#firstChoice').val() === str || $('#secondChoice').val() === str) {
        $('.additional').show();
    } else {
        $('.additional').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/aKqKR/7/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? If either of them is Option 1 then the div shows otherwise it hides it again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstChoice').on('change', function () {
        checkToShow();
    });
    $('#secondChoice').on('change', function () {
        checkToShow();
   });
});

function checkToShow(){
    if ($('#firstChoice').val() == 'Option 1' || $('#secondChoice').val() == 'Option     1') {
    $('.additional').css("display", "block");
    }
    else{
        $('.additional').css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKqKR/11/)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
$('.additional').hide();
$('#firstChoice,#secondChoice').change(function () {
    $('.additional').css('display', ($('#firstChoice').val() == 'Option 1' || $('#secondChoice').val() == 'Option 1') ? '':'none');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aKqKR/6/)**